# How to write a Google Script that send an email notification once a specific column has been edited?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to write a google script that will send me an email every time a specific column has been edited on google sheet.

The spreadsheet is titled "Sales" and the tab is "RO". Columns D to H will be edited with info on an irregular basis which is why I want to try set up an email notification to alert me when an edit has been made.

An error message saying

> Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.

appears when I try run the code

Here is the code:

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet("Sales").getSheetByName("RO");
if (be.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "Rollover") return;
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,4,1,5).getValue();
let n = rData[0][4];
let d = new Date(rData[0][3]).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
let amo = rData[0][7];

let msg = "Account ID " + n + " (" + d + ") Request Date " + "Transfer Amount " + amo;
Logger.log(msg);
GmailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com", "New Sale", msg)
}
```

Comment: About `An error message saying "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet." appears when I try run the code.`, I think that the reason for your issue is due to `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet("Sales").getSheetByName("RO");`. In your showing script, I thought that this can be removed. Because in your showing script `ss` is not used. And, can you provide your whole script including the function name?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to mention `Sales` if your script in bound to the spreadsheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RO")
```

edit : as you do not use ss in the script, try

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "ROLLOVER" || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != 'RO') return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4, 1, 5).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][4];
  let d = new Date(rData[0][3]).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  let amo = rData[0][7]; let msg = "Account ID " + n + " (" + d + ") Request Date " + "Transfer Amount " + amo; Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com", "New Sales", msg)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I removed the be to e - was a typo

Comment: ro correct the last issues, can you provide a minimal reproducible example? with the last correctons of the script!

Comment: function sendMailEdit(e){
var = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RO");
if (e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "ROLLOVER") return;
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,4,1,5).getValues();
let n = rData[0][4];
let d = new Date(rData[0][3]).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
let amo = rData[0][7];

let msg = "Account ID " + n + " (" + d + ") Request Date " + "Transfer Amount " + amo;
Logger.log(msg);
GmailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com", "New Sales", msg)

}

Comment: row 2 : you have omitted ss : `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RO")`

Comment: ... but you do not use ss in the script, see my updated proposal

Comment: Once I add in ss this error message appears now "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined". Now it appears the "if (e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "ROLLOVER") return;" is the issue

Comment: do not lanuch this script in the script editor; onEdit is fired when you will write manually something in the sheet

Comment: Is there a way I can remove the specific e.value so that when a general edit In column 3 is made I can get a notification?

Comment: no, because we want to know (within e) which row has been modified to send you the mail you expect

Comment: the purpose of e is to detect/catch the change (sheet, range,...) so that sendMailEdit will run as you expect with values; do not omit to define a trigger for sendMailEdit

Comment: Ah okay, so seems like the script works as when i make changes it shows successful completion in the execution log. But I am yet to receive any email even though I have set the trigger event to notify me immediately on edit

Comment: you should share your spreadsheet to be able to find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error message, remove

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet("Sales").getSheetByName("RO");
```

as `ss` is not used.

Also replace

```
be.range.columnStart
```

by (remove `b`)

```
e.range.columnStart
```

and replace

```
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,4,1,5).getValue();
```

by (add an `s` / use `getValues()` instead of `getValue()`)

```
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,4,1,5).getValues();
```

as it looks that these lines have typos.

Comment: Thank you! I've made the corrections but now I get an error message saying "Attempted to execute sendMailEdit, but could not save." and when I try to save the code it says "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=' line: 2 file: Code.gs"

Comment: @kevin20996 You are welcome. The new error doesn't look to be caused by the suggested changes.